# how to treat input as a generator

Tags: python, input, serial-port, generator

I am reading lines from a serial connection (pyserial), at the moment I am using a while loop to read the line and then perform a series of functions on that input and then store it in an object ( a range finder ) .

It has been mentioned that I should treat the serial input as a generator, as that is how things are done in python.

Does anyone have any experience with this?
Or could at least explain in principle how this would be achieved?
Why it is better? Is it purely for memory / speed?

EDIT:

where does the function:

```
at_end()
```

come from? 
I'm getting:

`AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'at_end'`

If I use

```
while True:
    yield source.readline()
```

then I get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a look at the [Iterator Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). Basically you implement a class:

```
class SerialReader(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        super(SerialReader, self).__init__()
        self.source = source

    def next(self):
        """Provide next piece of data from the serial source."""
        # If we have no more data, we have to raise StopIteration exception
        if self.source.at_end():
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return self.source.read()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

reader = SerialReader(some_serial_source)

for data in reader:
    do_something_with_data(data)
```

Advantage is the use of such iterator/generator - you can use it with any python method that accepts iterators:

- list comprehension: `sample = [data for data in serial_reader]`
- [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)
- qick and simple conversion to a list: `list(serial_reader)` - will read all the data and will return a list
- ... much more

Iterator is very pythonic pattern and you can meet quite frequently. Many python libraries make use of iterators.

Concerning memory usage: imagine you want to process your source with another function that accepts stream of data. You do not have to have load all source data, you just pass the generator (iterator) to the processing function and the data will be read as needed.

Comment: A generator function doing exactly the same thing as this class is `def serial_reader(source): while not source.at_end(): yield source.read()`.  Write less classes!

Comment: @SvenMarnach, where does the at_end() function come from? I can't seem to call it on my serial connection.

Comment: While it may seem pythonic, I can't imagine a real scenario where you would want to do this for serial data.  Serial data is normally coming in slowly and constantly from a stream.  It's not often like a blob of data that you want to iterate through.  You may have a packetized data format over the serial wire, but you can't preserve that fragmentation when doing a direct read on serial.  Don't be fancy just for the sake of it.  Reading your bytes in a loop is probably just fine.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is:

```
for x in myObject:
    # do stuff with x
```

this will iterate on values in myObject. For this to work the object has to implement the iterator protocol (see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). This will work on list, tuple, generators, dict ...

The nice thing is that you don't need the index, and that the object doesn't have to implement  `__getitem__`

Answer (score 0):

Python documentation is one of the best, so i'll just redirect you to [Generator documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators)

Yes, it is purely for memory and speed.

Comment: Note that PySerial ``Serial`` objects are iterators themselves, so you can just do ``for x in someSerialInstance: ...``.

Comment: I noticed xreadlines was function that seemed to be a generator as well